# Alternative for deprecated command() function in orientDB

Tags: java, orientdb, orientdb3.0

I'm using OrientDb java document api to query the database.My sample code is

```
OrientDB orientDB = new OrientDB("remote:localhost",OrientDBConfig.defaultConfig());
ODatabaseDocument dbConnection = orientDB.open("configurationDatabase","root", "root");
List<ODocument> date = dbConnection.command(new OCommandSQL("select date from Trial")).execute();
```

In this the dbconnection.command() function is displayed as deprecated , even though the orientdb documentation contains [this](http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/java/Document-API-Documents.html#sql-commands) . I'm Using orientdb 3.0.28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you are pointing at is for a version of the `command`method that is not deprecated.

The signature of the deprecated command is:

```
@Deprecated
<RET extends OCommandRequest> RET command(OCommandRequest iCommand)
```

Alternatives to the deprecated command are fully described in the [doc](https://orientdb.com/javadoc/develop/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/db/ODatabase.html#command-com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequest-):

- You have two different **command** versions

  > default OResultSet **command**(String query,Map args)
  >                               throws OCommandSQLParsingException,
  >                                      OCommandExecutionException
  >
  > default OResultSet **command**(String query, Object... args)
  >                           throws OCommandSQLParsingException,
  >                                  OCommandExecutionException
- And two alternative **execute** methods

  > default OResultSet **execute**(String language,
  >                              String script,
  >                              Map args)
  >                       throws OCommandExecutionException,
  >                              OCommandScriptException
  >
  > default OResultSet **execute**(String language,String script,Object... args)
  >                       throws OCommandExecutionException,
  >                              OCommandScriptException

Use the one that best suits your need.